Abstract class warning in PHPUnit 10.5
I am encountering an warning error in UnitTest cases, after upgrading from php7to php8, My folder structure is app/tests/cases/api/ In this folder I have all the test cases, I have one abstract class file BaseApiTest.php, I am using this file in all other testcases. I have tried to exclude the BaseApiTest.php file in Phpunit.xml and tried to supress the warning errors, but nothing is working..Please anyone suggest what I can do, so that the warning issue will be fixed. Thanks
Class app\tests\cases\api\BaseApiTest declared in /var/www/accounts.localhost/app/tests/cases/api/BaseApiTest.php is abstract
below is my sample codes
<?php 
namespace app\tests\cases\api; 
use accounts\test\Integration; 
use PHPUnit\DbUnit\DataSet\YamlDataSet;
  abstract class BaseApiTest extends Integration {
 } 
?> 

below is the phpunit.xml file
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="phpunit.xsd"
         bootstrap="tests/bootstrap.php"
         cacheDirectory=".phpunit.cache"
         beStrictAboutOutputDuringTests="true"
         failOnRisky="true"
         failOnWarning="true"
         colors="true">  <testsuite name="My Test Suite">
    <directory suffix="Test.php">./tests</directory>
  </testsuite>
  <source restrictDeprecations="true"
            restrictNotices="true"
            restrictWarnings="true">
    <include>
      <directory suffix=".php">src</directory>
    </include>
    <exclude>
      <file>app/tests/cases/api/BaseApiTest.php</file>
    </exclude>
  </source>
</phpunit>


Per this thread it sounds like the recommendation is to just rename the class to something that doesn't end in just Test

Thanks @ChrisHaas, The above post shed some light on my question, I will try to rename the abstract file name to BaseApiTestCase and will check.
and also I am thinking to upgrade PHPunit to 11 version, whether the issue will still fix or not
